# which memory limit applies when php performs a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, php, memory, memory-usage

If I run php as FPM, I can set my memory limit in  `php.ini` or `.user.ini`. PHP can perform a MySQL query, and I can set memory limits in `/etc/my.cnf` for for instance the innodb buffer pool. If PHP runs a query, which memory limit applies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are independent.  But, assuming you have both running on the same machine (this is not a requirement), they must share the available RAM.

`php.ini` has an *upper limit* for *each instance* of PHP.  Often the web server will launch many instances.  The default is usually adequate.  If you have *some* PHP pages that need more, you can do a set_ini at the start of any that might need more.  (Example:  image processing)  I do not change the limit until I encounter an "out of memory" message from PHP.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the *main* tunable for MySQL.  As a first cut, set it to 70% of *available* memory after allowing for reasonable usage by other apps.  I realize this is rather vague, but it usually works.

Comment: Thanks. But, when PHP delegates a query to MySQL, does it mean the work is no longer under the responsibility and therefor memory limit of PHP?

Comment: PHP's memory limit does not include MySQL's.  However, each will occupy some portion of RAM until PHP terminates.

Comment: So the memory PHP consumes in this hypothetical situation is the memory needed to pass the query to MySQL and other specific PHP stuff, and then MySQL consumes the memory it needs to perform the query under its own process?

Comment: @GuidoGoluke - Correct.  MySQL's memory is relatively large and constant due to its use of RAM for caching.  PHP has some space for the program, plus some transient space for data.  If, for example, you fetch a million rows from a table, PHP's RAM usage will grow by many MB briefly, while MySQL does not change much.

Comment: Ah yes, and on a sidenote, you can decrease the amount on memory PHP uses when iterating through MySQL rows by using a generator. OK, more clear now. Thanks!